# Mocking DynamoDB mapper query using Mockito

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, mockito, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-mapper

I am trying to mock a very simple line of code that is used to query the DynamoDB using Java. Here is some sample code for the query -

```
List<Pojo> result;
        try {
            if (filters == null) {
                this.queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Pojo>()
                        .withKeyConditionExpression(partitionKeyCondition)
                        .withExpressionAttributeValues(this.eav);
            } else {
                setFilterQueryExpression(filters);
            }
            result = this.dynamoDBMapper.query(Pojo.class, queryExpression);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new InternalServerException("Something went wrong with the database query: ", e);
        }
```

The above piece of code works and I am able to retrieve a List of rows that automatically get deserialized into the Pojo.

I am now trying to Mock the `this.dynamoDBMapper.query` call as follows -

```
@Mock
private DynamoDBMapper mapper;
List<Pojo> result = new ArrayList<>();

when(mapper.query(Pojo.class,Mockito.any(DynamoDBQueryExpression.class)).thenReturn(result);
```

I am unable to do that with error -

```
Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(java.util.List<com.amazon.xxx.xxx.Pojo>)'
```

I also tried another way -

```
doReturn(result).when(mapper).query(Pojo.class, Mockito.any(DynamoDBQueryExpression.class));
```

That seems to compile but the test fails with error -

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue
```

I have looked at other sample where the expected output of the query is of type `PaginatedQueryList` , I have tried changing to that as well. But I am still not sure why the above throws an error.

Comment: Have you tried changing List<Pojo> to PaginatedQueryList<Pojo> or similar? According to the documentation the query methods return specific implementations of List. You can assign a specific implementation to a more general List variable but you cannot return a more general type where a specific implementation is requested per the signature. Hence, Mockito cannot resolve the method you are asking for.

Comment: I did try changing the return type from `List` to `PaginatedQueryList` but the `when` still does not accept it. It says `Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(PaginatedQueryList<Pojo>)'`. I feel like I need to do something extra to make it work but I am not entirely sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also get the error when you use ArgumentMatchers?

```
Mockito.when(mapper.query(ArgumentMatchers.any(Pojo.class),ArgumentMatchers.any(DynamoDBQueryExpression.class)).thenReturn(result));
```

Do you also get the error if you expand the ArgumentMatchers (temporarily)?

```
Mockito.when(mapper.query(ArgumentMatchers.any(),ArgumentMatchers.any()).thenReturn(result));
```

Comment: Yes, it does not change anything. I have already tried replacing the arguments with `any()`.

Comment: @Samarth Can you go into the .query() method and check the return type? Is it List<Pojo> or is it a base class? WrongTypeOfReturnValue and Cannot resolve method List<...Pojo> hints somehow that the return value is false. Also check if the return value is something like List<? extends something> because then your Pojo need to extend  "something" as well.

Comment: The return type is `PaginatedQueryList` as described in the documentation. I have tried switching all the return types in my code from `List` to `PaginatedQueryList` but I still run into the error. See comment on question for more.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, you are missing a parenthesis before `.thenReturn` in order to complete the `when` part. Once you add it and switch from return type `List` to `PaginatedQueryList`, it should compile. Also note that `any` is a matcher. Once you specifiy a matcher, all arguments need to be matchers, therefore use `eq` etc. for your Pojo type. Otherwise, Mockito will show a `InvalidUseOfMatchersException` during runtime. Here is a simplified example that works for me:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBQueryExpression;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.PaginatedQueryList;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class MockTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        DynamoDBMapper mapperMock = mock(DynamoDBMapper.class);
        PaginatedQueryList<String> expected = mock(PaginatedQueryList.class);
        // Note that when needs to be completed before thenReturn can be called.
        when(mapperMock.query(eq(String.class), Mockito.any(DynamoDBQueryExpression.class))).thenReturn(expected);

        QueryService queryService = new QueryService(mapperMock);
        PaginatedQueryList<String> actual = queryService.query();

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    public class QueryService {
        private final DynamoDBMapper mapper;

        public QueryService(DynamoDBMapper mapper) {
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        public PaginatedQueryList<String> query() {
            DynamoDBQueryExpression<String> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<>();
            return mapper.query(String.class, queryExpression);
        }
    }
}
```